# Text resizing in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, text, html

I'm trying to create a book type interface that has 'pages', and the user can manually resize text, the catch is that I don't want the text to ever scroll.

I was using the 
[studio HTML5](http://studio.html5rocks.com/samples/slides/index.html#slide1) demo as a starting point, the problem is as any given text is allocated to one slide, so as the text size is increased the slide sizes just increase and it doesn't scale well.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Wait a minute, you want to increase the font size but don't want the text to scroll or resize the container. That's crazy, like trying to fit an elephant in a suitcase.

Comment: @Ben no, I think he wants to change font size so the text fits into the container.

Comment: No, he wants the text to fit to the page, and the overflow would spill over to the next page.

Comment: Then damn that will be a coding hell, handling all those cascade overflows.

Comment: What @Pekka wrote in his answer is pretty much true. By their nature, the HTML renderers don't give access to the sort of information you'd need to make this work - specifically, they don't explicitly tell you about how much text fits in a box. You can sort-of figure out how big text is to see if it's (probably) caused a scrollbar to appear, but it'd be a great effort to make something like that very solid and bulletproof.

Comment: @Mike_Sherov has explained better than I have. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but one view is that HTML is not the right language for this - what you want can probably be achieved somehow using jQuery, but it's likely to be really kludgy.

There is no native way of doing this, say by having a text block that gets a certain width, and its contents scaling to that width. Every resize of the window would have to trigger a complex recalculating operation.

I *think* this would be solvable much better, and smoother, in Flash.

Comment: Why do people vote things down without providing an explanation? If you don't like what somebody's said, you achieve nothing (other than the irritation of people trying to be helpful) through a silent downvote. *This is what comments are for.*

Comment: Not to mention you could also add a fancy "page swap effect" in a less painful way.

Comment: Sadly Flash isn't an option.  Thanks for the tip. I'll have a read around the jQuery demo/examples and see if anything comes close/can be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `em` unit. when use properly, the font scale based on its parent. This give you some point of reference.

So if you get the parent font (let say body or your page) to be in ratio with the size of the page (use jQuery to ensure that). Then every child fonts will be automatically in ratio.

I did my thesis defense in Feb using HTML/CSS/jQuery. I create a power point like program. It scaling reasonably well. Let looks at [my blog](http://blog.nawaman.net/2010/01/cssjavascript-technique-for-setting-font-size-based-on-the-page-size/) here.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it'll be useful.